# Selenium "get_screenshot_as_file" failed with Jenkins

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, screenshot

So i have below script:

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('captured_test.png')
```

And works fine when it executed in shell/terminal. But not when using Jenkins, building process seems deadlock while trying generate the screenshot file.

Comment: You may need write permission on jenkins jobs workspace or where you are saving that file.

Comment: @Murthi already did

Comment: The solution is to change the jenkins configurations: JENKINS_HOME and UserName

Changing the 2 variabels into current user.